# Create a inherited class with user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm trying to code a product inventory project. I stumbled across this problem and have been searching since a few days but couldn't find any way to do it. How can I create a class inherited from the base class with user input..

Here is the base class:

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, title, color, price):
        self.title = title
        self.color = color
        self.price = price
```

what I'm trying to achive is that user will be able to add products himself by lets say pressing 2 will ask him to enter the product type (coat) and than the parameters specific to the product which will create a new class inherited from the base class. Like this:

```
class coats(Product):
    def __init__(self, material, size):
    self.material = material
    self.size = size
```

I can create instances with user input but creating inherited classes I couldn't figure it out. I appreciate if you could help. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you need to generate new classes? Just store the user-selected parameters in a dictionary.

Comment: What have you tried? Is there a way you can tell the parent class what it's attributes should be for the child? (there is....)

Comment: Since ```coats``` is a ```Product``` it should take ```title, color, price``` as arguments and pass those to ```Product.__init__``` in its ```__init__``` function.

Comment: @NathanMcCoy I messed with __new__ but didn't work. I'm pretty new in programming and trying to learn as much as I can with such projects but I feel like I'm way over my head on this one... :) Appreciate If you can point the way..

Comment: Look into `super()`, seems like what you want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can generate classes dynamically with the [`type()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type), you really do *not* want to do this here. Code generation to model user-generated data only leads to very, very difficult to manage code that looks up attributes and variable names dynamically.

Use a datastructure *in your existing class* to store user-generated data. All you need is a dictionary:

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, type, price, properties):
        self.type = type
        self.price = price
        self.properties = properties
```

then to create a `coat` product use:

```
products = {}
products['coat'] = Product('coat', 10.0, {'color': 'some color', 'material': 'some material', size: 12})
```

where the various values, and the key in `products` are not literals but variables with user input.

Classes model your application, and *contain* the data. Don't create separate models for the data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate, It took me a while to understand. I thought that the code creates a dictionary in products which I could then print it like `print(products['coat']['color']` but no, it loads the parameters into properties in class which i could then print with `print(products['coat'].properties['color']` I didn't even know this was possible... Thanks alot. When it comes to my original question I guess as Nathan McCoy suggested, super() is the way to go. Any chance you can explain how it can be done just for the information ?

Comment: @Seferi: that comment assumed you were actually creating subclasses directly, not generating them. See [Understanding Python super() with \_\_init\_\_() methods](//stackoverflow.com/q/576169) for a post on how `super()` can be used in `__init__` methods to have a base class handle some of the configuration.